# Access value of Struct data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to access value in a struct defined as `mydata:struct<1:array<int>>`.
I tried accessing using `mydata.1` but it is not a valid syntax.

Sample data `{1=[154873, 155630, 157698, 157945, 159058, 163148]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply quote the `1` with double quotes:

```
SELECT mydata."1" FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be queried using [unnest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html) operator.You can use below query to fetch the items from array :

```
select t1.* from test cross join UNNEST("mydata"."1") as t1(record);
```

Comment: The unnest is not necessary for to achieve what the OP is asking – which is merely how to access the `1` property of the struct.